# How to add bulleted relevant coursework to Jake's resume?

Tags: lists, cv, resume, bullets

Want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Link to source code for Jake's resume: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jakes-resume/syzfjbzwjncs

Comment: The best solutions to problems like this often depend on things like what document class is being used, what packages are loaded, etc. A [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of your code would help kickstart things for those offering solutions.

Comment: @frabjous added the source code link

Comment: Perhaps try a `minipage` environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to load the `multicol` package in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
```

And then put a "resumeItemList" as defined by template inside a 3-column `multicols` environment, something like this:

```
\section{Relevant Coursework}
\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \resumeItemListStart\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \resumeItem{Computer Programming}
    \resumeItem{Data Structures}
    \resumeItem{Analog Electronics}
    \resumeItem{Digital Electronics}
    \resumeItem{Signals and Systems}
    \resumeItem{Semiconductor Material}
    \resumeItemListEnd
\end{multicols}
```

I put in a negative `\vspace*` there because I think you get too much space between the section title and list otherwise, but adjust as desired.

The exact style in the image you posted doesn't match the hierarchy or bullet spacing in the template, so mine looks a little different.

[image: bullets in columns examples]

Of course you might prefer to this inside a Sub-heading list and use the `\resumeSubHeading` command instead of `\section` depending on exactly how you wanted things arranged.

See also the [multicol package documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf).

EDIT: The above solution uses the commands defined in the template. Those definitions look like this:

```
%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1 & #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}
```

If you didn't want to keep these definitions, or were using a different template, you can achieve more or less the same result without using the command defined by the template (so within another document class, etc.) with:

```
\header{Relevant Coursework}
\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\itemindent}{-2em}
\item Computer Programming
\item Data Structures
\item Analog Electronics
\item Digital Electronics
\item Signals and Systems
\item Semiconductor Material
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't render the bullets and correct spacing. I get the error "undefined control sequence"

Comment: I did add the use{multicol} line in the imports

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem is out of context. I did test my code before posting, so you must be doing something differently from what I'm doing. Can you post a minimal but complete document that generates the error (either by editing the original post/question or linking to it via a pastebin site)?

Comment: And this was probably just a typo, but of course it's `\usepackage{multicol}` not simply `\use{multicol}`.

Comment: https://pastecord.com/wejimigazy.tex

Comment: The code you posted at pastecord is missing half the template! -- either you removed it, or the template Overleaf in fact uses is different from what you get from "View Source" when you visit the link you posted in the question. (I don't have an Overleaf account so I can't check.) Restore the "custom commands" section from `\newcommand{\resumteItem}...` through the `\newcommand` for `\resumeItemListEnd`. If you don't want to do that for some reason, I put some alternative code at the end of my answer, but I suspect other things in the template will break without those commands defined.